# Entity Framework database-first: accessing 2 foreign keys names from same table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two tables - one is the `Customer` table which has 2 columns which are both foreign keys to the `Cars` table.

`Customer` table:

```
xid  Name    Prev_CarID(fk Cars)  Current_CarID(fk Cars)
--------------------------------------------------------
1    Ben        2                      1
2    Frank      1                      3
3    John       3                      2
```

`Cars` table

```
id   Name    
-------------
1    Ford
2    BMW
3    Volvo
```

I am trying to get the following result

```
CustomerName PreviousCar  CurrentCar
-------------------------------------
Ben             BMW          Ford
Frank           Ford         Volvo
John            Volvo        BMW
```

In my method I wrote code like this:

```
var result = Context.Customers
                    .Select(o => new Models.Customers()
                                     {
                                         Name = o.Name,
                                         PreviousCar = o.Cars.Name,
                                         CurrentCar = o.Cars.Name,
                                     })
                    .ToList();
```

I'm not getting the correct values.

How do I get the correct values for this?

Answer (score 0):

could you use joins?

```
   var result = from customers in context.customers
    join previousCar in context.cars on customers.prevCarId equals previousCar.Id
    join currentCar in context.cars on customers.currentCarId equals currentCar.Id
    select new
    { Name = customers.Name,
      PreviousCar = previousCar.Name,
      CurrentCar = currentCar.Name
    }
```